# How to left align a container (Bootstrap 5)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a container (grid, Bootstrap 5) and I want to left align it on my page.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col border border-dark m-2">
      Col1
    </div>
    <div class="col border border-dark m-2">
      Col2
    </div>
    <div class="col border border-dark m-2">
      Col3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to have all cols and row to be left aligned on my page. I could use `position-absolute top-0 start-0` on the container div, but according to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/position/#position-values) the page would not be responsive anymore. How to fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the CSS for the *.container* class, it has the left and right margins aligned at **auto**. This centers content on the page. Technically, your row/columns are left aligned in the container. If you want the container truly left-aligned, overwrite the CSS with

```
.container {
  margin-left: 0!important;
  margin-right: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: You are right, good catch - Thx. I was able to achieve the same output by simply applying the m-0 class to the container to handle all margins

Answer (score 0):

the edges on the sides are given by the container tag, in this example below I used the container-fluid class to make it take as much space as possible to the container and removed the data margins from the m-2 class :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col border border-dark ">
      Col1
    </div>
    <div class="col border border-dark">
      Col2
    </div>
    <div class="col border border-dark">
      Col3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```